# How do you map json in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, api

I'm trying to show the following Json in a table using react, but I'm not sure how I can access the elements that are inside the JsonArray of **empresas**, **Bodega_Origen** y **Bodega_Destino**.

```
  {
        "Estado": 1,
        "_id": "5e31ecf510ec6117387548a1",
        "usuarios": "5e262750803c451ca4a27c36",
        "empresas": {
            "_id": "5e2f4c3ef80d8246f0e545d8",
            "Nombre_Empresa": "ING. Y HER. S.A."
        },
        "Tipo_Documento": "AF",
        "Numero_Documento": "1",
        "Bodega_Origen": {
            "_id": "5e2619ccbb29d71aa8455cad",
            "Descripcion": "BODEGA PRINCIPAL"
        },
        "Bodega_Destino": {
            "_id": "5e2629f110b9f32d10524ca5",
            "Descripcion": "BODEGA Obra parma"
        },
        "Responsable": "Mauricio",
        "Estado_Documento": "PR",
        "Observaciones": "",
        "Detalles": [],
        "Fecha_Creacion": "2020-01-29T20:37:09.919Z"
    }
```

The following is the method I am using to obtain the data and parse it. You are currently browsing the data correctly, but it does not show the data that is within the Bodega_Origen y la Bodega_Destino.

```
  loadData(){
        var cont = 0;
        console.log('Getting list');
        const activeTab = this.state.activeTab;
        const ids = this.ids;
        const path = activeTab===0?'/empresa/list':'/articulo/list';
        console.log(this.state.listQuery);
        cont++;
        console.log(cont)
        return this.Requests.list(path, this.state.listQuery).then(response=>{
            if(response && response.length !== 0){// El request no ha devuelto un arreglo vacio
                let dt = response;
                dt.map((el,i)=>{
                    let filterProperties = [];//Propiedades de interes
                    filterProperties[i] = {};//Inicializar el objeto para cada elemento del arreglo
                    ids[activeTab].forEach(key=>{
                        if(el[key]._id){
                            el[key] = el[key].nombre;
                        }
                        filterProperties[i][key] = el[key];
                    })
                    return filterProperties;
                });
                console.log(dt);
                let stateData = this.state.data.slice();
                stateData[activeTab] = dt.slice();
                this.setState({data:stateData});
            }else{
                let stateData = this.state.data.slice();
                stateData[activeTab] = [];
                this.setState({data:stateData})
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: That is not an array.

Comment: @CarlosDnl are you getting multiple objects like this or only one. if it's only one then it's an object not array

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To access that json data you will need to specify it:

```js
data.empresas
data.Bodega_Origen
data.Bodega_Destino
```

In that way you access the nested json object. JSON is an object type, not an array. Hope this helps :)

Answer (score 0):

Per se an Object is not iterable. You cannot map an Object like an Array in React. You can try it with **Object.entries(obj)** and then loop over those key, value pairs and get what you want.